# error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment linux

Tags: c

I am working on raspberry pi.and writing code for Keypad in linux.
I have defined a macro

```
#define ALL_COL_HIGH  ((GPIO_SET(COL1) | GOIO_SET(COL2) | GPIO_SET(COL3) | GPIO__SET(COL4)))
```

Whenever i am using `ALL_COL_HIGH` getting error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment, and set function definition is

```
#define GPIO_SET(g)  *(gpio.addr + 7) |=  (1<<(g))
```

Comment: A pair of parenthesis might fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

An advise: always close body of an expression macro into parenthesis:

```
#define GPIO_SET(g)  (*(gpio.addr + 7) |=  (1<<(g)))
```

Using your original macros, the macro `ALL_COL_HIGH` was expanded into something like:

```
((  *(gpio.addr + 7) |=  (1<<(g)) |   *(gpio.addr + 7) |=  (1<<(g)) | ....   ))
```

which is parsed as:

```
((  *(gpio.addr + 7) |=  ( (1<<(g)) | *(gpio.addr + 7) ) |=  ((1<<(g)) | ....  ))
```

from where you can see that on the left side of the assignment `((1<<(g)) | *(gpio.addr + 7)) |=  ...` there is an expression which is not an l-value.

Closing the body of `GPIO_SET` into parenthesis will fix the problem.